# Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Connection leak while running

Tags: c#, .net, memory-leaks, asp.net-web-api, red-gate-ants

After stress testing my application, with *Ants Memory Profiler (v 7.4.0.41)* running, I found *22,395* different object instances of the class *Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Connection*.

The application type profiled was set to *"ASP.NET web application (web development server)"*.

Is this a problem with the Ants Memory Profiler, since it itself starts up the server instance, or is this a problem with Cassini?

The number of instances found is equal to the number calls during my stress test.

Anyone got an idea about this, or has run into this themselves?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say. It looks like the Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Connection type is a strongly-typed wrapper over a socket connection. If your load test is establishing HTTP/1.1 sessions, I'd expect the connections to stay "alive" because connections persist in HTTP 1.1 until they are closed by the requester.

But if you want, you can send the ANTS results to Red Gate support and we can use them to trace the object references back to the root. The Instance Categorizer is meant to show how the objects are rooted... http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/features/instance-categorizer

Comment: I see the same behaviour reported by Ant Memory Profiler in my application. Did you determine whether it was a fault in your application or a characteristic of Ant?

Comment: I don't recall getting to the bottom of it and I don't work for Redgate any more, so I'd suggest contacting them.